# How can this puzzle be solved without guessing?

Tags: sudoku, difficulty-rating

[image]This puzzle was given to my 8 year old from the school. My child was struggling, so I gave it a bash, but was unable. I do sudoku regularly so know most methods of solving. I gave it to my husband and he got to the exact same point as me. Just wondering if this can be solved without guessing in any way?

Comment: Source appears to be: https://www.education.com/worksheet/article/generated-kayak-sudoku/

Comment: Yes, the school did provide an answer sheet when requested. Which showed I was correct up until I got stumped. I felt like there was one number too few in the puzzle, so I’m just trying to see if a better puzzle solver has been able to do it without guessing

Answer (score 8):

As a standard sudoku, this puzzle does not have a unique solution.  It has 31 possible solutions.  This was verified using the [Sudoku Solver by Andrew Stuart](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm).

Therefore it cannot be solved in a usual logical way unless the "Kayak" lends another wrinkle to the ruleset.

Comment: How do you determine this?

Comment: @BenBarden See my edit. :)